# Oracle SQL and PHP search range

Tags: php, html, sql

I am building a dictionary and want to limit the number of results the user can get. In my HTML page, I have a set of radio buttons that define the range in which the user can limit is search. 1 = simple, 2 = easy, 3 = meduim, 4 = hard, 7 = all. This is defined by a database value attached to the entries, Difficulty. I am trying to limit the search with the following code, but it is not returning any results. $search_limit is the radio value.

```
if(strcmp($search_limit, '1'))
        {
            $sql .= ') and (Difficulty is null or Difficulty = 1) and          rownum<=500' . $search_order;
        }
    elseif (strcmp($search_limit, '2')) 
    {
            $sql .= ') and (Difficulty  >= 1 or Difficulty <= 3) and     rownum<=500' . $search_order;
        }
        elseif (strcmp($search_limit, '3')) 
        {
            $sql .= ') and (Difficulty  >= 4 or Difficulty <= 6) and     rownum<=500' . $search_order;
        }
        else
        {
            $sql .= ') and (Difficulty <= 7) or rownum<=500' . $search_order;
        }
```

What I am having trouble with is the (Difficulty >= x or Difficulty <= x). If I default the search limit to the else statement, it returns everything with difficulty 7 (the max) and under correctly. Similarly, if I replace the 7 in the else statement with any other number below 7, it also works correctly. I just can't get the defined search to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching for a range, you should use `x >= y AND x <= z`... otherwise if you use `OR` you will return everything.

So change...

```
Difficulty >= 1 or Difficulty <= 3
```

To...

```
Difficulty >= 1 and Difficulty <= 3
```

Also, your `else` has different logic, as it is has `or rownum<=500` when all the others have `and rownum<=500`

Answer (score 0):

> Difficulty >= 1 or Difficulty <= 3

This is true always (except when Difficulty is null): every number is greater than 1 or less than 3.

You must mean

```
Difficulty >= 1 AND Difficulty <= 3
```